# How to set Background color of Panel to transperent

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I've set my panel config to: `bodyStyle: 'background:transparent;'` but it's not working. I've also tried: `defaults: { bodyStyle: 'background:transparent;' }`.

```
function cre1ColumnHboxForModErrMsg(itemA){
    var hb = new Ext.Panel(
        {   layout:'fit'
            ,height:75
            ,frame: false
            ,border: false
            ,bodyStyle: 'background:transparent;'
            ,layoutConfig:{ align:'top', pack:'center' }
            ,defaults:{ layout:'form', labelWidth:CampConst.CampModErrMsgLabelWidth ,width:175,border:false}
            ,items:[
                {   width:((CampConst.CampModErrMsgWidth/2)-30)
                    ,defaults:{ labelSeparator:'', msgTarget:'side', selectOnFocus:true,anchor:'95%' }
                    ,items:[
                        itemA
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    );
    return hb;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Why are you nesting an extra item?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I use it to generate my form .. cre1ColumnHboxForModErrMsg(creValidateTextArea('Myanmar Error Message','post_cpME_MM',CampConst.CampModEM_MSG))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `style: 'background:transparent;'` - this applies to the overall panel element rather than just the body.

However that being said it looks like you don't really need a panel , and could replace with a container:

```
function cre1ColumnHboxForModErrMsg(itemA){

    var hb = new Ext.Panel(
        {   layout:'fit'
            ,height:75
            ,frame: false
            ,border: false
            ,bodyStyle: 'background:transparent;'
            ,layoutConfig:{ align:'top', pack:'center' }
            ,defaults:{ layout:'form', labelWidth:CampConst.CampModErrMsgLabelWidth ,width:175,border:false}
            ,items:[
                {   width:((CampConst.CampModErrMsgWidth/2)-30)
                    ,defaults:{ labelSeparator:'', msgTarget:'side', selectOnFocus:true,anchor:'95%' }
                    ,items:[
                        itemA
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    );
    return hb;
}
```